# How to send a email from my mobile app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, email, cordova-plugins, oracle-jet

I have a list of employee details in which email details are also present .
Once I click the mail icon of one employee it should either call the email app in the mobile or open a page where I compose and send a mail.

I tried cordova plugin email composer.but I couldn't make it out

Can anyone help me or suggest me blogs using which I can implement.

The code I tried is

```
self.sendEmail=function() {

 cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
function (isAvailable) {
     alert('Service is not available'); //unless isAvailable; 


cordova.plugins.email.open({
app: 'mailto',
subject: 'Sent with mailto'
})
});
}
```

Comment: are you testing this on real mobile device?. i found this [link](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/send-email-android-ios-ionicframework/). try this link

Comment: yes .I tested in android mobile

Comment: @Dinesh Unable to add the plugin is there any other example

Comment: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-email)

Comment: [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2016/06/11/hybrid-mobile-app-development-2sending-email-app)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I can't understand why you alert always that the service is unavailable. You have an `isAvailable` variable which holds if it is or it is not enabled. 
This line that you copied from the official link means that you should check if isAvailable is true or false. 
For example

`isAvailable ? alert('available') : alert('not available');`

Then you need to have a correct email account set up in order to use the plugin. So the device needs to be able to send emails.

Then you are missing the callback which can give you important details about the event and you are not using all the needed properties in a correct way.

```
cordova.plugins.email.open({
    to:          Array, // email addresses for TO field
    cc:          Array, // email addresses for CC field
    bcc:         Array, // email addresses for BCC field
    attachments: Array, // file paths or base64 data streams
    subject:    String, // subject of the email
    body:       String, // email body (for HTML, set isHtml to true)
    isHtml:    Boolean, // indicats if the body is HTML or plain text
}, callback, scope);
```

So your code should look in this way:

```
cordova.plugins.email.open({
to: ['receiver address or multiple elements for more'],
subject: 'Sent with mailto',
body: 'body of the email!'
}, function(data) { alert('callback'); alert(data);}, this);
```

Comment: Thank you @quirimmo 
However I used this single line  in my javascript code 
window.open('mailto:mailto@gmail.com?subject=subject&body=body');